# Understanding how parent and child components handle an object

Tags: angular

I'm wondering how angular handle an object shared between a parent and child component.

Let me show you a simple example:
**ParentComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `<app-children [(data)]="message"></app-children>
            <div>Parent: {{message}}</div>`,
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  public message: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = 'Original message'
  }
}
```

**Children Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-children',
  template: `<div>Children: {{data}}</div> 
             <a (click)="changeMessage('Children message')">Click me!</a>`
})

export class ChildrenComponent {
  @Input() public data: string;
  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.data = message;
  }
}
```

When I click on the "Click me!" link, i see only the Children message change, but not the parent one. Isn't it the same object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that **it's not the same object**, because you **completely reassign** it **to the new one** here:

```
changeMessage(message: string) {
  this.data = message;
}
```

If you want to see whether it changes in parent component when you change it in child component, **you have to change it**, **not create a new one**, for example:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<app-children [data]="data"></app-children>
            <div>Parent: {{data.message}}</div>`,
})

export class AppComponent {
  public data = { message: "" };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.message = 'Original message'
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-children',
  template: `<div>Children: {{data.message}}</div> 
             <a (click)="changeMessage('Children message')">Click me!</a>`
})

export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() public data: { message: string };
  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.data.message = message;
  }
}
```

[Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-between-parent-and-child-co-gdzgcy?file=src/app/app.component.ts).
Here we pass an **object** (where **message it's just a field**) to child component, and **we modify object inside the child component**, and changes being **reflected in both components**. Despite the fact that **it works**, it's **not recommended to change** an object **inside of child components**, for these purposes **it's better to use** **@Output + EventEmitters**. Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that for the eventEmitter property, you have to name it exactly as the input property name, followed by "Change". In this example Input() was data, Output dataChange. If the input was test the Output should be testChange.

Answer (score 4):

consider you should emit the changed value from child and also your emitter name should be `[your bind var name]+'Change'` so it will work:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<app-children [(data)]="message"></app-children>
            <div>Parent: {{message}}</div>`,
})

export class AppComponent {
  public message: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = 'Original message'
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-children',
  template: `<div>Children: {{data}}</div> 
             <a (click)="changeMessage('Children message')">Click me!</a>`
})

export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() public data: string;
  @Output() dataChange= new EventEmitter<string>();
  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.data = message;
    this.dataChange.emit(this.data);
  }
}
```

check [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-between-parent-and-child-co-bap9qq)
and [creating custom two-way data bindings](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html#creating-custom-two-way-data-bindings).